# Creating Options in Combo Boxes as Available Serial Ports

Tags: java, swing, serial-port, jcombobox, event-dispatch-thread

So, I'm confused as to how to change the options in a combo box based off of the available serial ports. Could anyone please help me figure this out? I think I need to use javax.swing.getModel, but I'm unsure as to how to do that.

```
  if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
        ArrayList<String> serialports = new ArrayList<String>();
        serialports.add(portId.getName());
        String[] ports = new String[serialports.size()];
        ports = serialports.toArray(ports); 
        GUI.jComboBox2 = new JComboBox(ports);
        GUI.jComboBox2.addActionListener(GUI.jComboBox2);
        wantedPortName = (String) GUI.jComboBox2.getSelectedItem();
```

Comment: 1. for better help sooner post an SSCCE, short, runnable, compilable, just about JFrame, JComboBox and code for looking in the local port, 2, OS returns ports with significant delay, then  you have an issue with Concurency in Swing (Oracle tutorial), then you would to use SwingWorker (in the case that you have some skills with Java) otherwise look at Runnable#Thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues...because of the lack of context, it's difficult to know which one is correct

### Possibility #1

You've previously created the combo box and added it to the screen....

If this is the case, then your code has just de-referenced it.  Meaning that the control that is on the screen is no longer the one you are interacting with.

In this case, you should update the model only...

```
ArrayList<String> serialports = new ArrayList<String>();
serialports.add(portId.getName());
String[] ports = new String[serialports.size()];
ports = serialports.toArray(ports); 
ComboBoxModel<String> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(ports);
GUI.jComboBox2.setModel(model);
```

### Possibility #2

You've never added the combo box to the screen before...

In which case, you should...but there's not enough context to describe how you would achieve that with your code...

### Possibility #3

I have no idea what you're talking about...

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific, but your solution #1 did turn out to be the answer. Thanks!